# Determining smoothing parameter in HP filter for hourly data

Tags: time-series, matlab, econometrics, filter

I'm trying to determine a smoothing parameter for the Hodrick-Prescott filter. I've seen that there are papers on the topic but they are far too advanced for my comprehension. If I have a data set, $X$, what are the steps to take?

My data is hourly. Using MATLAB I know the smoothing parameter values for monthly data etc., but how can I compute it for hourly data?

Comment: Can you edit this to provide more information? For example, what software are you using? As it stands, the question is too vague to be answerable. You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) or [this blog post](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) regarding how to ask a statistical question. Note that, if this question cannot be made answerable, it will need to be closed.

Comment: Thanks, @xian, I think that may make this question answerable. So you would know how to do this if you had monthly data, but don't know how to convert that value when you are using *hourly* data, is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right. Is there an equation to follow?

Answer (score 2):

The equation you are looking for is
$$\lambda_\alpha = \frac{1}{\alpha^4}\lambda_1$$
which is the adjustment factor derived by [Ravn and Uhlig (2002)](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/mh5/class/econ489/Ravn-Uhlig.pdf). They derived the smoothing factor for annual data with this formula using the $\lambda = 1600$ for monthly data which was originally suggested by Hodrick and Prescott. That is
$$\lambda_{\text{annual}} = \frac{1}{4^4}1600 = 6.25 $$

You can re-arrange the equation and then solve the optimal smoothing factor for any data frequency. You can get the monthly smoothing factor from
$$12^4 \cdot 6.25 = 129,600$$
where 12 is the data frequency in months. Now you just need to know how many hours there are in a year which, according to Google, is 8765.81 and then you just plug it in again to get some very large number:
$$8765.81^4 \cdot 6.25 = 36,901,857,672,400,771.793$$

I doubt though that this will get you far because the Hodrick Prescott filter was developed for aggregate macro data in order to study business cycles at a quarterly, annual or at most monthly frequency. The filter was not meant to be for hourly data and I cannot imagine that it will perform well for your kind of application. For instance, if you search on Google scholar for Hodrick-Prescott "hourly data" you will not find anything. So even though this should answer your question, I would still be vary of using this result.